# Ansys ironpython ACT does not run

Tags: python, xml, ironpython, ansys

I am trying to make the code work from the 9-17min mark in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oX5hDU0Qg-Q

I wrote down every single line of code and it should work, however I get the following errors when opening Ansys:

```
unexpected token 'ExtAPI' at line 69 in file C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v202\Addins\ACT\extensions\ACT_NumPy_Ex3\main3.py: 
ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("Scalled Ux contour plotted from ACT_Numpy_Ex3 Extension")
index out of range: 1 
IndexOutOfRangeException 
at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.FixIndex(Int32 v, Int32 len) 
at IronPython.Runtime.List.get_Item(Int32 index) 
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) 
at $3.(CodeContext $globalContext, FunctionCode $functionCode) in C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v202\Addins\ACT\extensions\ACT_NumPy_Ex3\A_NumpyFun3.py:line 45 
at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx) 
at Ansys.ACT.Core.Extension.ReadScripts() 
Unable to find callback method 'oninit', named 'init', in python file.
Unable to find callback method 'onclick', named 'CreateCustomPost_1', in python file.
```

I know for a fact that line 69 should not be generating an error so the error must be somewhere else. I also do not understand how the last two lines of errors can occur as they should work as expected.

When opening Ansys only the initialization function init is supposed to run, everything else is supposed to run after I click a button.

I have attached the xml file that is used to initialize everything in Ansys and for ui generation, along with the main ironpython file.

```
<extension version="192" minorversion="0" name="ACT_NumPy_Ex3">
    <guid shortid="ACT_NumPy_Ex3">98V1CB96-4EEE-4DF2-AA62-EC8F9838543A</guid>
    <author>SanthoshM</author>
    <description> Asd
    </description>
    <script src="main3.py" compiled="true"/>
    <script src="A_NumpyFun3.py" compiled="true"/>
    <interface context="Mechanical">
        <images>images</images>
        <callbacks>
            <oninit>init</oninit>
        </callbacks>

        <toolbar name = "ACT_NumPy_Ex3" caption = "ACT_NumPy_Ex3">
            <entry name = "ACT_NumPy_Ex3" icon = "hand">
                <callbacks>
                    <onclick>CreateCustomPost</onclick>
                </callbacks>
            </entry>
        </toolbar>
    </interface>
    
    
        <simdata context ="Mechanical">
        
            <result name="CustomRes" version="1" caption="CustomNumPyRes" icon="hand" location="node" type="scalar" >
                <callbacks>
                    <evaluate>Manupulate</evaluate>
                </callbacks>
                
                <property name="Geometry" caption="Geometry" control="scoping"> </property>
                <property name="DispFactor" caption="DispFactor" control="float" default="5.0"> </property>
                <property name="InputFileName" caption="Input csv File Name" control="text" default="auto" readonly="true"> </property>
                <property name="OutputFileName" caption="Output csv File Name" control="text" default="auto" readonly="true"> </property>
                
            </result>
        
        </simdata>
        
</extension>
```

```
clr.AddReference("Ans.UI.Toolkit")
clr.AddReference("Ans.UI.Toolkit.Base")
import os
import subprocess
import units
from Ansys.UI.Toolkit import *

def init(context):
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("Intializing Numpy maniuplate ...")

def CreateCustomPost(analysis):
    analysis.CreateResultObject("CustomRes", ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension)


def Manupulate(result, stepInfo, collector):
    step = stepInfo.Set
    analysis = result.Analysis
    reader = analysis.GetResultsata()
    reader.CurrentResultSet = step
    Disp=reader.GetResult("U")
    #DispUx=Disp.GetNoteValues(66)[0]
    mesh = analysis.MeshData
    
    WorkingdirName = analysis.WorkingDir
    InstallDir = ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.InstallDir
    OneUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(ExtAPI.DataModel.AnalysisList[0].WorkingDir,'..')
    TwoUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(OneUp, '..')
    ThreeUp=System.IO.Path.Combine(TwoUp, '..')
    UserFiles=System.IO.Path.Combine(ThreeUp, '..')
    
    AnsResfilesname=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.Name + "DispUx_Input.csv" #Ansys raw results
    ManResfilename=ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.Name + "DispUx_Output.csv" #Results manuplted with Numpy
    
    ipfile=os.path.join(UserFiles,AnsResfilename)
    opfile=os.path.join(UserFiles,ManResfilename)
    #ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(ipfile)
    #ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(opfile)
    
    fl=open(ipfile,"w")
    
    nodeIds = collector.Ids
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(str(nodeIds))
    for nId in nodeIds:
        #ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage (Str(nId) +"'''"+str(Disp.GetNodeValues(nId)[0]))
        fl.write(str(nId)+","+str(Disp.GetNodeValues(nId)[0])+"\n")
    fl.close()
    
    scaleFactor=result.Properties["DispFactor"].Value
    result.Properties["InputFileName"].Value =AnsResfilesname
    result.Properties["OutputFileName"].Value =ManResfilename
    
    callCpython(scaleFactor, UserFiles, ipfile,opfile)
    
    import csv
    resfile=opfile
    reader=csv.reader(open(resfile, 'rb'),quoting=csv.QOUTE_NONNUMERIC)
    NodeNos = next(reader)
    ScaledUxs=next(reader)
    a=int(NodeNos[1])
    b=ScaledUxs[1]
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(a.GetType().ToString())
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(b.GetType().ToString())
    userUnit = ExtAPI.DataModel.CurrentUnitFromQauntityName("Lenght")
    DispFactor = units.ConvertUnit(1, userUnit, "m")
    
    for id in collector.Ids:
        collector.SetValues(int(NodeNos[NodeNos.index(id)], {ScaledUxs[NodeNos.index(id)] * DispFactor})  # The value to display
    
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("Scalled Ux contour plotted from ACT_Numpy_Ex3 Extension")
    return True
    

def callCpython(scaleFactor,UserFiles,ipfile,opfile,input=None):

    InstallDir = ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.InstallDir
    python372=r"C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" ### Your Cpython .exe file location
    PyinputFile=os.path.join(InstallDir, "A_NumpyFun3.py")
    
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(str(scaleFactor))
    
    process=subprocess.Popen([python372,PyinputFile,UserFiles,ipfile,opfile,str(scaleFactor)])
    process.wait()
    
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on line 67. It currently reads:

```
collector.SetValues(int(NodeNos[NodeNos.index(id)], {ScaledUxs[NodeNos.index(id)] * DispFactor})  # The value to display
```

and it needs to read

```
collector.SetValues(int(NodeNos[NodeNos.index(id)]), {ScaledUxs[NodeNos.index(id)] * DispFactor})  # The value to display
```

You were missing a closing bracket on the `int`

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code but I made these modifications and it's working now.
In short, you need to define the "result" variable before using it in the other functions

```
def __init__(context):
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("initiating Scipy manipulate...")
    pass  

def CreateCustomPost(analysis):
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage("clicked on CustomPost button")
    result=analysis.CreateResultObject("CustomPost")
```

Comment: When using your modifications the code will not run at all for me. Are you sure that is all you have changed?

Comment: Yes I think so! make sure to change the version number in the xml file to be sure it's updated